# function undefined error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller.js file

```
function AppCtrl ($scope) {

    console.log("hello world from controller");
    person1={
        name:'soniya',
        email:'jodhanisoni@gmail.com',
        number:'(111) 111-1111'
    };
    person2={
        name:'rajat',
        email:'rj@gmail.com',
        number:'(222) 222-2222'
    };
    person3={
        name:'john',
        email:'john@gmail.com',
        number:'(333) 333-3333'
    };

    var contactlist=[person1,person2,person3];
    $scope.contactlist=contactlist;
}
```

Please help me to get rid of it.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Spelling error with `AppCtrl `? Add more code and errors.

Comment: I wrote function AppCtrl($scope)
can u tell what spelling mistake?

Comment: Write full code. This chunk is totally ambiguous ... What are u trying to achieve explain.

Comment: can you create a plunker? spelling mistake may be appCtrl vs AppCtrl

Answer (score -1):

Though I do not fully understand your question, but I think you are trying to do this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js" ></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<p ng-repeat="x in people">{{x.name}},{{x.email}},{{x.number}}</p>
    <script>
        //1 app declaration
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        //3 controller declaration
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.people = [
            {name:'soniya',email:'jodhanisoni@gmail.com',number:'(111) 111-1111'},
            {name:'rajat',email:'rj@gmail.com',number:'(222) 222-2222'},
            {name:'john',email:'john@gmail.com',number:'(333) 333-3333'}
          ] 
        });
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Run the code. Hope your problem is solved.